# Running Docker Image with AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to configure AWS ECS to run a Docker image that has an application running on port 3000. When I configure my ECS container to forward host port 80 to container port 3000 ECS tells me that my container is up and running. However, going to the public IP for my EC2 instance results in a timeout (instead of the application home page, like I would expect).

The funny thing is, if I ssh into my EC2 instance and restart the image manually I can navigate to the application on port 80 in my browser just fine. Here is the command I use to run the image manually:

`docker run -i -t -p 80:3000 <image>`

Does anyone know why ECS port forwarding doesn't work when manual startup and port forwarding does? What could I be missing?

Comment: How does your task definition look like? Is the docker container running when you first ssh into the instance?

Comment: Yeah, the Docker container was running when I first sshed into the instance. I gave up on ECS and switched to running Docker on an EC2 instance myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suspect that the issue is your Security Group does not have port 3000 open. As a test, add a TCP rule with a Port Range of `3000` change the source to `Anywhere` `0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, re:

_The funny thing is, if I ssh into my EC2 instance and restart the image manually I can navigate to the application on port 80 in my browser just fine. Here is the command I use to run the image manually:_

`docker run -i -t -p 80:3000 <image>`